# Using a list of dynamic links throughout website

Tags: html, css, iframe

By "dynamic links", I mean a list of links that will constantly be updated.

To illustrate my question, I have a website that I am constantly writing new articles for. I currently have about 10 articles. If someone is to read article #5, there is a list of links to all 10 articles  in the right panel of the page. As I update the site, and article #1 becomes out of date, I'd like to replace article #1 with article #11. Rather than updating the links within every article (so 10 times), is there a way to update the links once and have them all update simultaneously to every page?? Could I create an iframe for this??

Thanks for any and all help!

Comment: It sounds like you're new to web dev. Read into dynamic web development using things like PHP or CMS (content management systems). The sort of thing you're describing is very normal and every-day; it just needs a bit of tutorial time.

Comment: Ok, yes I am new and have much to learn. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

What's your goal? Do you want to learn to be a web developer? Or are you mostly concerned with getting your articles published?

If you want to be a web developer, I'd recommend steering clear of large CMS system like Wordpress or Drupal. Those are great products. But you want to learn the basics first. I think starting a PHP tutorial is the way to go.

If you just want to publish your articles, I'd recommend you find a nice place to create a blog. There are so many to choose from. It all depends on how much you want to spend.

Feel free to ask follow up questions. Web development sounds simple. But it's really a complex topic. I can't imagine what is must be like starting out these days with so many choices and competing technologies.

Comment: I would like to be a web developer but I feel just now getting comfortable with html css. It has been quite the journey and is fairly difficult to comprehend when you first get started. I wanted to create my site from scratch so learn would be more hands on so I tended to stay away from wordpress and drupal.I have a book on javascript and jquery, but those seem to be a bit over my head at this point. I'll look into using PHP next.

Comment: Unless you're using something like [http://nodejs.org](Node) or [https://www.meteor.com](Meteor) to run code on a web server (as opposed to serving static web pages), generating dynamic pages, you'll need to dig in to a language like PHP, Python, Ruby, or many others that run on a web server. You Javascript/jQuery book is most likely meant to teacher browser or client-side coding. As I said, this is a complex topic. You can use Javascript on the server; but having just one language to learn doesn't really make things any easier.

Comment: A complete web application usually employs several "languages." I used scare quotes because I don't consider some of them languages. They are usually: HTML, CSS, Javascript, PHP (or other), and SQL (or other: noSQL). In some cases you can replace server-side PHP and SQL with Javascript. Meteor comes to mind. As does Node JS paired with Mongo DB (a popular combo).

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it would be to use Server-side includes. ([Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Side_Includes)) They work like this:

```
<!--#include file="some-content.html" -->
```

or

```
<!--#include virtual="some-folder/some-content.html" -->
```

The difference is `file=""` finds a file relative to the current page, whereas `virtual=""` finds it from the domain root. Either way, this method can use any type of regular text file as a source. The actual addition of the content is done by the server (hence the name) so its contents will be parsed as regular HTML and all CSS will apply to it as if the file were part of your page. I don't know about compatibility with different hosts, but if your web server supports it, this is probably the easiest way to go.